# Dealing with different architectures when loading data using stdio

Tags: c, stdio

I want to read in some data from a file.  Say an integer:

```
fread(&var1, 4, 1, f);
```

Where var1 would be an integer.  But then I got to thinking that this is not safe as there isn't any guarantee that an integer is 4 bytes long.  (I'm ignoring other issues like feof and ferror for the sake of this question).

I also soon realised that there were even more issues than just int size, such as the endianness of the system, and probably others which I haven't even thought of.

So, what is the best way to ensure that you data being read in is interpreted properly?  So far, the only thing I can think of is to just store the data as text rather than as binary data, read in the text, and convert it at run time.  I would guess that no matter the solution though, if you wanted to ensure that it is portable, it would always involve some form of conversion anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Tricky situation, if you are going to deal input like this, perhaps you don't have much option but to support all possible environment. However, taking input using "more common functions" such as scanf() implicitly performs environment based porting. As for fread(), I am also eager to know ideal ways to consider different environment.

Comment: Check the documentation of the vendor who gave you the file. It will say in which binary format integers are stored in it.

Comment: This is why XML is so popular.

Comment: @Kerriek, well, I've made the file, and I know what format they're stored in (as it was my computer that made it), I just am trying to make sure that other people can use the data as well.

Comment: @Hans, so you would recommend reading it as text, and converting it to binary data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the size problem, you should be doing:

```
fread(&var1, sizeof(var1), 1, f);
```

If you're worried that the size of `int` might vary between the platform that writes the data and the platform that reads the data, then you have a more fundamental problem.  In this scenario, you should avoid using `int`, `short`, etc., and use the types defined in `<stdint.h>`, such as `int16_t`, `uint32_t`.

To deal with endianness issues, you should consider writing helper functions that explicitly write/read the individual bytes in a known order, such as:

```
void write_uint32_t(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t x)
{
    buf[0] = (uint8_t)(x >> 0);
    buf[1] = (uint8_t)(x >> 8);
    buf[2] = (uint8_t)(x >> 16);
    buf[3] = (uint8_t)(x >> 24);
}
```

All of the above applies only to integer types.  For floating-point types, there is no perfect universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Always use  `sizeof()` operator for getting size of types. Never rely on hard coded values!